# PSR4 not working

Tags: php, composer-php, psr-4

I have setup a folder structure like this for a package of legacy classes

```
vendorname/legacy/src/ClassA.php

namespace Vendorname\Legacy;
class ClassA{}

vendorname/legacy/src/Folder/Class2.php
namespace Vendorname\Legacy\Folder;
class FolderClass2{}
```

With composer I'm loading this from a github repo like this:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "git@bitbucket.org:username/vendorname-legacy-classes.git"
    }
],
"require": {
    "vendorname/legacy": "master@dev"
}
```

When I load ClassA like this it works:

```
use Vendorname\Legacy\ClassA;

$a = new ClassA();
```

However none of my subfolder'd classes work:

```
use Vendorname\Legacy\Folder\FolderClassB;

$b = new FolderClassB();



Class 'Vendorname\\Legacy\\Folder\\FolderClassB' not found
```

I have already defined the source folder with a file vendor\vendorname\composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendorname/legacy",
    "description": "Vendorname Legacy classes",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vendorname\\Legacy\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "master": "master"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define one thing more to your composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Vendorname\\Legacy\\": "vendorname/legacy/src/"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this has not helped. I had already defined this in a composer.json file, but tried your version as well and ran composer update afterwards. Any other ideas?

Comment: @jdog Because your class name is inconsistent `class FolderClass2` should be in `FolderClass2.php` file not in `Folder/Class2.php` (either change class name or file name/location)